# Intercept email in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, postfix-mta

I have server with Postfix. I need to write application for intercepting incoming emails with controller to parse it and redirect to appropriate method. How to do this?

Comment: Do you want to catch all incoming mails?

Comment: Yes, I want catch all incoming mails

Comment: Maybe it could be useful https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler

Answer (score 0):

You can simply forward all mails received in postfix to any address or any user in the server.

You can use the virtual files in the postfix.

/etc/postfix/main.cf:
      virtual_alias_domains = example.com 
      virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

/etc/postfix/virtual:

@example.com         anybody@yet-another-site

In this the example.com is the domain. If you have more than 1 domain then you should add the other line for that domain and remember to add that domain in virtual_alias_domains.

For more info you can refer this [link](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) and see the  Mail forwarding domains session